# Eclipse RCP - Exclude source file from Plugin build

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm building an Eclipse Plugin project (Eclipse 4.2) and I want to exclude a "work in progress" .java source file from my build. So I right-clicked the file and selected `build --> exclude`

But when I export the Plugin, errors from the "wip" source are caught, because it seems still **included** in the build process.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to create a second source folder and not add the output folder to the build.properties

Comment: Thx. It could be a solution (as would be renaming the source file) but I prefer to keep the project structure unchanged since I'm working in a version controlled environment. I'm wondering if I stumbled in a bug or I'm missing the standard way to manage exclusions in an RCP development.